# Http error 416 Requested range not satisfiable, using Google Drive Rest API on Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Below is the piece of code. The code works correctly, except on one instance for one of the user using Samsung Tab 10.1

```
String pageToken = null;
do {

    FileList remoteImageList = mService.files().list()
            .setSpaces("appDataFolder")
            .setPageToken(pageToken)
            .setQ("mimeType='image/webp'")
            .setPageSize(10)
            .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
            .execute();
    for (com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file : remoteImageList.getFiles()) {

        File newLocalImage = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), file.getName());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newLocalImage);
        mService.files()
                .get(file.getId())
                .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(fos);
        fos.close();

    }
    pageToken = remoteImageList.getNextPageToken();
} while (pageToken != null);
```

Below is the message in the IOException.

```
416 Requested range not satisfiable
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "requestedRangeNotSatisfiable",
    "message": "Request range not satisfiable"
}
],
"code": 416,
"message": "Request range not satisfiable"
}
}
```

From the code, I can see that the error is generated when calling executeMediaAndDownloadTo method. The implementation of that method uses MediaHttpDownloader (part of Google API), and the implementation looks correct. The only thing I can think of is that the Samsung Tab 10.1 device has a different implementation of the Google API, which might have a bug?

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Have you tested this with multiple devices? Are you using browser when open drive? Found this [HTTP error 416](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68298)

Comment: @d.datul1990 thanks for the link. The cause of the error was in the code pushing the data into Google Drive. I was using an android service to push the data within a synchronized onStartCommand. But it seems that there were simultaneous uploads and it was corrupting the files in the Drive. (I reproduced the issue by forcing simultaneous uploads on my test device). I synchronized the upload with a static object and that resolved the problem. Now I'm wondering if some devices have an issue and allow multiple instances of service?

Answer (score 8):

The issue is probably that you're trying to download a file that has been created without any content. Every time you try to fetch a file like that, you will receive a 416. To fix this you can update the file with data.

Comment: any other reason why it can happen? my files are not empty